# Point babel-loader to different tsconfig.json file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

Is there a way to point babel-loader to a specific `tsconfig.json` file? We have a project that uses multiple ones (one is used by tsc, other one by Webpack) and I have found no way to tell babel-loader to use a specific one.

Thank you.